# php mail() - Can I send multiple different emails from one script?

Tags: php, html, email

I've looked all over the internets to try and find the answer to this but have found nothing whatsoever.

I have a signup button on my site, and when somebody signs up with their e-mail I would like 2 things to happen:

1. Email is sent to me to notify that somebody has signed up
2. Different mail is sent to the new member with a welcome message and further information.

I currently have a signup form which has a mail() function attached, but I can only figure out how to use this to send one message. Up till now I have used it only to notify me.

Is there a way to send more than one message?

The HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="signup.php">
   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="content2"/>
   <input type="submit" class="special" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The contact.php is

```
<?php

  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

    $headers .= "Reply-To: My Site <my@email.com>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Return-Path: My Site <my@email.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: My Site <my@email.com>\r\n"; 

  mail( "my@email.com", "Signup Request", "Signup request from $email", "$headers" );
  header( "Location: thankyou.html" );

?>
```

Comment: Just send the second email using another `mail()` function?

Comment: Of course you can. Just copy-paste your code, and change the information in the second copy.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had tried adding a second mail() function but it didn't work so assumed it wasn't possible. It must have just been my error. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, you could easily use 2 mail functions:

```
<?php

  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

    $headers .= "Reply-To: My Site <my@email.com>"; 
    $headers .= "Return-Path: My Site <my@email.com>";
    $headers .= "From: My Site <my@email.com>"; 

    mail( "my@email.com", "Signup Request", "Signup request from $email", "$headers" );
    mail( "my@email.com", "Welcome", "Welcome to this site!", "$headers" );
    header( "Location: thankyou.html" );

?>
```

If you wanted to just use 1 mail function, it may be possible to use arrays and a *for* loop, like this:

```
<?php

  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

    $headers .= "Reply-To: My Site <my@email.com>"; 
    $headers .= "Return-Path: My Site <my@email.com>";
    $headers .= "From: My Site <my@email.com>"; 

    $subject = array("Signup Request", "Welcome");
    $content = array("Signup request from $email", "Welcome to this site!"); 

    for($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++;){
        mail( "my@email.com", $subject[$i], $content[$i], "$headers" );
    }    

    header( "Location: thankyou.html" );

?>
```

Here is a Muddal tutorial going through how to do this in a little more depth: https://muddal.com/muddaltut.php?id=140